# How to create Decision table in csv file - Drools?

Tags: java, csv, jboss, drools

I am new bee to Drools. I'm good to create a decision tables in Excel format by following the documentation

https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.32.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_wb.artifactrepository

But I can't find any specific documentation for creating decision tables in csv files. I'm aware of that drools supports decision tables in csv format too.

Any one please advise sample format or documentation/links for creating  decision table in csv format.

Comment: Have you tried to doing a 'Save As CSV' on your existing excel decision table?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes- But it's not working. Throwing a exception while firing the rules org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: No RuleTable cells

Comment: So the drools documentation currently says that only XLS and XLSX file formats are supported (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-tables-defining-proc).) There's one mention of CSV for the decisiontables jar but I think that's a leftover/oversight. Unless you're willing to downgrade to Drools 6, I think you're stuck with XLS[X].